# Split sentence into fixed-sized chunks using word boundary and POS

Tags: java, string, recursion, split, nlp

I'm trying to split a sentence into fixed chunked keyword phrases based on word boundary and POS (part of speech) using Java (please see updated code at the end of this post)

**1)** Disregard certain POS

**2)** Certain POS cannot function as root keyword.

And produce the following output:

```
**Root Keyword:** In
**Phrase:** None
```

---

```
**Root Keyword:** 2017
**Phrase:** None
```

---

```
**Root Keyword:** Joe Smith
**Phrase:** None
```

---

```
**Root Keyword:** announced
**Phrase 1:** In CD, NNP announced he was
**Phrase 2:** CD, NNP announced he was diagnosed
**Phrase 3:** NNP announced he was diagnosed with
**Phrase 4:** announced he was diagnosed with Lyme
```

---

```
**Root Keyword:** diagnosed
**Phrase 1:** CD, NNP announced he was diagnosed
**Phrase 2:** NNP announced he was diagnosed with
**Phrase 3:** announced he was diagnosed with Lyme
**Phrase 4:** he was diagnosed with Lyme disease
```

The last possible word to generate phrase for is: *disease*

```
**Root Keyword:** disease
**Phrase 1:** he was diagnosed with Lyme disease
```

**So far I've implemented the following code:**

```
public class Sentence {


    public Sentence()
    {

    }


    ArrayList<Word> wordList = new ArrayList<Word>();

    public void addWord(Word word)
    {
        wordList.add(word);
    }

    public ArrayList<Word> getWordList() {
        return wordList;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Word {

    public Word(String word, String pos) {

        this.word = word;
        this.pos = pos;
    }


    String word;
    String pos;
    ArrayList<String> phraseList = new ArrayList<String>();


    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public String getPos() {
        return pos;
    }


    public void setPhraseList(ArrayList<String> phraseList)
    {
        phraseList.addAll(phraseList);
    }

}
```

---

```
public void generatePhrases()
{


    Sentence sentence = new Sentence();
    sentence.addWord(new Word("In", "IN"));
    sentence.addWord(new Word("2017", "CD"));
    sentence.addWord(new Word(",", "PUNCT"));
    sentence.addWord(new Word("Joe Smith", "NNP"));
    sentence.addWord(new Word("announced", "VB"));
    sentence.addWord(new Word("he", "PRP"));
    sentence.addWord(new Word("was", "VBD"));
    sentence.addWord(new Word("diagnosed", "VBN"));
    sentence.addWord(new Word("with", "IN"));
    sentence.addWord(new Word("Lyme", "NN"));
    sentence.addWord(new Word("disease", "NN"));
    sentence.addWord(new Word(".", "PUNCT"));


    ArrayList<String> posListNotUsedAsRootKeyword = new ArrayList<String>();
    posListNotUsedAsRootKeyword.add("NNP");
    posListNotUsedAsRootKeyword.add("CD");


    ArrayList<String> posListNotCountedTowardMin = new ArrayList<String>();
    posListNotCountedTowardMin.add("VBD");
    posListNotCountedTowardMin.add("IN");
    posListNotCountedTowardMin.add("PRP");
    posListNotCountedTowardMin.add("TO");

    int minPhraseLength = 4; 
    int maxPhraseLength = 6;


    for (int wordCounter = 0; wordCounter < sentence.getWordList().size(); wordCounter++) {

        ArrayList<String> phraseList = new ArrayList<String>();


        Word word = sentence.getWordList().get(wordCounter);
        String wordAsStr = word.getWord();
        String pos = word.getPos();

        if (posListNotUsedAsRootKeyword.contains(pos) || posListNotCountedTowardMin.contains(pos)) {
            continue;
        }


        boolean phraseDesiredLength = false;

        String phrase = wordAsStr;
        int phraseCounter = wordCounter + 1;
        while (!phraseDesiredLength && phraseCounter < sentence.getWordList().size()) {

            Word phraseWord = sentence.getWordList().get(phraseCounter);
            String phraseWordAsStr = phraseWord.getWord();
            String phrasePOS = phraseWord.getPos();


            String appendPhrase = (posListNotUsedAsRootKeyword.contains(phrasePOS)) ? phrasePOS : phraseWordAsStr;
            phrase += " " + appendPhrase;

            if (StringX.countNumberOfWordsInStr(phrase) == minPhraseLength || StringX.countNumberOfWordsInStr(phrase) == maxPhraseLength) {

                phraseDesiredLength = true;
            }


            phraseCounter++;
        }


        System.out.println("PHRASE: " + phrase);

        phraseList.add(phrase);

    }

}
```

I'm primarily having difficulty generating phrases that begin before root keyword and end after root keyword (recursion?) and verifying phrase length == min or max phrase length.

Answer (score -1):

I have this feeling that you're doing too many checks for your phrasing, its confusing.
I would have a database with keytypes (VBD, IN, NNP, CD,TO...) and associated keywords to be my "dictionary", then I would evaluate:

if there's more keytypes that are undesired, do the if checks for the desired ones,

if there's more keytypes that are desired, do the if checks for the undesired ones.

That would make the code shorter.
Then I would go for the user input of text, where they would input something like:

`Peter Griffin likes small white cats snoring on the couch`.

That sentence would then be parsed on your `generatePhrases()` where first block would sort the phrase into a StringList, that "sorting" would be checking each word on the dictionary to determinate its keytype and check that keytype if its desired then I would remove from that StringList the pieces that aren't desired (NNP, CD, VBD, IN, PRP, TO) because you have more desired word types, so doing the undesired check is quicker.

```
String textinput = "Peter Griffin likes small white cats snoring on the couch";
String[] words = textinput.Split(" ");
StringList validwords = new StringList();

for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++){
    //do the SQL prepare thing, sqlite checks and all the good stuff...
    validword = "SELECT keytype FROM dictionary WHERE word = " + words[i] + 
    " AND keytype NOT IN ('NNP', 'CD', 'VBD', 'IN', 'PRP', 'TO')";

    validwords.add(validword);
}

if (validwords.size() >= 4) && (validwords.size() <= 6){
  system.out.println("Phrase: " + validwords.toString());
}
```

So that would leave me with a StringList with only the wanted words for my keyword sentence, then I would just do a check if the StringList lenght is between 4 and 6 and then just concatenate the words from the indexes with the `StringList.toString()` method.

Since you'd be inputting the text in an order that makes sense, you wouldn't have to check if `Snoring couch cat Griffin small Peter` makes sense, because it would already be ordered like `Peter Griffin likes small white cats` since its the order of the input.

Comment: @S.O.S -- this isn't a freelancer site where you submit your specifications and someone on the internet writes your code for you. This is a Q&A site for programmers to help each other.